Quill 2.0.2 не работает <br> перенос строки в редакторе Shift + Enter
Не могу разобраться почему в редакторе Quill 2.0.2 не хочет срабатывать комбинация Shift + Enter, чтобы перенестись на новую строку с помощью . Упорно создаёт новый параграф  будто нажат был только Enter. Официальная документация кроме этого ничего не пишет:


var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow'
});

quill.keyboard.addBinding({
  key: 13,  // Enter key
  shiftKey: true
}, function(range, context) {
  quill.insertText(range.index, '\n');
  quill.setSelection(range.index + 1);
});



Это работать не хочет

Получилось решить ?
